# Trying to count number of enteries in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

trying to count number of enteries in a database table. heres my code

```
var numberOfPeople = from rs in db.Results
                     select rs.E_Mail.ToList().Count().ToString();
```

Im trying to output this in a label using string. format. Its given me this error

> Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'

Answer (score 1):

You're applying `ToList` to `E_Mail` property. Just do that:

```
var numberOfPeople = from rs in db.Results
                     select rs.E_Mail;

var count = numberOfPeople.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert each `Email` to `List` and then getting the count and calling `ToString` on it. You are **missing brackets**. Your call should be like:

```
var numberOfPeople = (from rs in db.Results
                     select rs.E_Mail).ToList().Count().ToString();
```

Or you can simplify it like:

```
var numberOfPeople = (from rs in db.Results
                     select rs.E_Mail).Count().ToString();
```

Since you are only interested in `Count`, there is no need to get all the records in memory. Also Count would return a numeric value, it is better if you store its numeric value and then convert it to a string if you need. like:

```
int numberOfPeople = (from rs in db.Results
                     select rs.E_Mail).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

your whole query can be simplified to:

```
var numberofpeople = db.Results.Count.ToString();
```

you don't need the rest to simply count the rows.